# Dockerizing an already existing Symfony project

Tags: php, docker, symfony

I am trying to automate the development of a project I am currently working on by creating a container on Docker that is composed of mysql, php and nginx to run a Symfony project. Here is my docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  database:
    container_name: database
    image: mysql:8.0
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: rapidhcm
      MYSQL_USER: admin
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
    ports:
      - '4306:3306'
    volumes:
      - ./docker/mysql:/var/lib/mysql

  php:
    container_name: php
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - '9000:9000'
    volumes:
      - ./rapid-backend:/var/www/public
    depends_on:
      - database

  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    ports:
      - '8080:80'
    volumes:
      - ./rapid-backend:/var/www/public
      - ./docker/nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    depends_on:
      - php
      - database
```

And here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:8.0-fpm

RUN apt update \
    && apt install -y zlib1g-dev g++ git libicu-dev zip libzip-dev zip \
    && docker-php-ext-install intl opcache pdo pdo_mysql \
    && pecl install apcu \
    && docker-php-ext-enable apcu \
    && docker-php-ext-configure zip \
    && docker-php-ext-install zip

WORKDIR /var/www/html

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

RUN curl -sS https://get.symfony.com/cli/installer | bash
RUN mv /root/.symfony5/bin/symfony /usr/local/bin/symfony
RUN git config --global user.email "email@email.com" \ 
    && git config --global user.name "Damian Kowalski"
```

The Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml files are in the root folder of the project, however the Symfony index.php file is situated in ./rapid-backend/public/index.php. How can I indicate that I want to serve that php file?

Answer (score 1):

You would typically use only two containers: one for the database and one for the php-enabled web server.

You start from an php+apache image or an nginx image with php installed. Then you can bind-mount the web server's configuration files just as you did in your docker-compose.yaml for the nginx container.

You'd have something like this in your `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM php:8.2-apache AS production

ADD default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/default.conf

RUN # <...>
    # Install tools and PHP dependencies
    # apt-get update && \
    # apt-get install -y <...> && \
    # Configure docker php extensions, see image documenation on dockerhub
    # docker-php-ext-configure <...> && \
    # docker-php-ext-install <...> && \
    # Maybe you want xdebug? In that case you'll also want to copy a .ini file
    # pecl install xdebug && \
    # Cleanup
    # docker-php-source delete && \
    # Install latest composer 2
    # curl https://getcomposer.org/composer-2.phar > /usr/local/bin/composer && \
    # chmod +x /usr/local/bin/composer && \
    # Enable some apache mods if needed
    # a2enmod rewrite headers expires xsend && \
    # Some more cleanup if needed
    # apt-get remove -y <...> && \ 
    # apt-get clean

# If this image is to be used in a development environment, here you may want to create a user that you'll tell Apache to use with APACHE_RUN_USER, using the same UID as your own user on your host, so that you can bind-mount your sources in your docker-compose.yaml file without having permission issues.

# If however this is a deployment image, here you will probably want to "COPY" your source code in the image and to "RUN composer install".
```

with the appropriate apache configuration file `default.conf` that exposes your index.php (see the Symfony documentation at https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html for example configuration files).

Then your web server service in `docker-compose.yaml` could look like:

```yaml
web-server:
  build:
    context: .
  ports:
    - '8080:80'
  # If this is a dev environment, bind mount your source code, maybe also
  # have a "user: ..." option here if you created one in the Dockerfile
  volumes:
    - ./rapid-backend:/var/www/public
```

It's a pretty open question but I hope this is a push in the right direction. Starting from here you can use `docker-compose exec` to run a `bash` shell inside your web server, and use `composer` to install Symfony and initialize your project.